# each variables match I need to click a particular link and get data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I have list which has multiple links. Each variables match I need to click a particular link and get data.

I have written the below code. When it executes, it gives me **only AAA data (and not BBB**) and a **`stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`** error.

The reason for this is because the element to which you have referred is removed from the DOM structure but I have no idea how.

```py
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

    mypage_url  = driver.current_url
    myitems = soup.select('#myitemList a')
    for myitem in myitems:
        print(myitem.text)
        item_url = urljoin(mypage_url, myitem.attrs["href"])
        driver.get(item_url)
        sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        A = "AAA"
        B = "BBB"

        trs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#item_contents > table > tbody > tr")
        for i in range(1,len(trs)):
            names = trs[i].find_element_by_css_selector("td > p > span")

            sleep(1)

            if A  in names.text:
                trs[i].find_element_by_xpath("td/ul/li[1]/input").click()
                sleep(2)
                print(A)
            elif B in names.text:
                trs[i].find_element_by_xpath("td/ul/li[1]/input").click()
                sleep(2)
                print(B)
                break
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

This is the HTML structure is as below

```html
<div id="myitem" class="panel">
  <div class="side-box">
    <p class="tt"><span></span></p>
    <div class="ct">
      <ul id="myitemList">
        <li id="myitem_21" class="itname">
          <div style="">
            <a href="">shop1</a>
          </div>
          <div style=""></div>
        </li>
        <li id="myitem_23" class="itname">
          <div style="">
          <a href="">shop2</a>
          </div>
          <div style=""></div>
        </li>
        <li id="myitem_54" class="itname">
          <div style="">
            <a href="">shop3</a>
          </div>
          <div style=""></div>
        </li>
        <li id="myitem_94" class="itname">
          <div style="">
            <a href="">shop4</a>
          </div>
          <div style=""></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="bt"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th id="title"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="clear">
     <p style="">
       <span>AAA
         </span>
     </p>
     <ul class="clear">
       <li><input type="button" name="select" value="" onclick="listClick();"></li>
         <li><input type="button" name="list" value="" onclick="modelClick()"></li>
     </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="altn">
    <td class="clear">
      <p style="">
        <span>BBB
         </span>
      </p>
      <ul class="clear">
       <li><input type="button" name="select" value="" onclick="listClick();"></li>
         <li><input type="button" name="list" value="" onclick="modelClick()"></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="clear">
      <p style="">
        <span>CCC
          </span>
      </p>
      <ul class="clear">
       <li><input type="button" name="select" value="" onclick="listClick();"></li>
         <li><input type="button" name="list" value="" onclick="modelClick()"></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="altn">
      <td class="clear">
        <p style="">
         <span>CCC
           </span>
        </p>
        <ul class="clear">
         <li><input type="button" name="select" value="" onclick="listClick();"></li>
           <li><input type="button" name="list" value="" onclick="modelClick()"></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="clear">
      <p style="">
        <span>DDD
         </span>
      </p>
      <ul class="clear">
       <li><input type="button" name="select" value="" onclick="listClick();"></li>
         <li><input type="button" name="list" value="" onclick="modelClick()"></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Stale element exceptions happens when the page reloads the DOM structure either after a click on a page/ loads a new elements to the page. In your case, does the page loads anything after the click() ?

Comment: yes.the page loads data after the click()